# Grafico de barras Chart.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

Hola estoy intentando renderizar un grafico de barras vertical con chart js, en el cual necesito los labels del eje x y las leyendas respectivas, intente con esta configuracion:

```
public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['Bodega 1', 'Bodega 2'];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [];

   public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [65], label: 'Bodega 1' },
  { data: [80], label: 'Bodega 2' }
  ];
```

investigando encontré que para mostrar las leyendas debo incluir en cada item de los datos el atributo label lo cual lo hace perfecto, pero al momento de renderizar la gráfica muestra dos barras por cada label horizontal, y no he encontrado la manera de que sean independientes para cada barra es decir cada label horizontal corresponde a una barra, dejo un codigo que ilustra claramente el problema que tengo.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-sbnrc5

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé exactamente lo que quieres hacer, pero tienes dos datasets (conjuntos de datos), cada uno con dos etiquetas.
Tienes dos opciones:

#### Un dataset con dos etiquetas:

```
public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['Bodega 1', 'Bodega 2'];
public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
public barChartLegend = true;
public barChartPlugins = [];

public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
  { data: [65,80], label: 'Bodegas',
    backgroundColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)','rgb(0, 0, 250)'] } 
  }
];
```

#### Dos datasets, con una etiqueta en cada uno:

```
public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['Bodegas'];
public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
public barChartLegend = true;
public barChartPlugins = [];

public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
  { data: [65], label: 'Bodega 1' },
{ data: [80], label: 'Bodega 2' }
];
```